# Pass data from a form to a table on a different page - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, knockout.js

I want to know, Is it possible to update a table on one page using the user input from a form on a different page?

Note: In my project I am using nodejs to create the server, bootstrap for front-end and knockout, jQuery and standard JS at the back-end.

This is the section of code where I create the table:

```
<div id="cTable"> 

 <table id="contract_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1">Contract Ref.</td>
            <td id="td2">Farm Ref.</td>
            <td id="td3">Type</td>
            <td id="td4">Variety</td>
            <td id="td5">Grade</td>
            <td id="td6">Season</td>
            <td id="td7">Created Date</td>
            <td id="td8">Agreed Date</td>
            <td id="td9">Est. As Grown Qty</td>
            <td id="td10">Committed Qty</td>
            <td id="td11">Optional Qty</td>
            <td id="td12">Moved Qty</td>
            <td id="td13">UOM</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <!-- Array bound to table --> 
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: contractReference"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: farmReference"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: productType"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: productVariety"></td>  
            <td data-bind="text: grade"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: season"></td> 
            <td data-bind="text: dateCreated"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: dateAgreed"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: asGrown"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: committed"></td>  
            <td data-bind="text: optional"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: moved"></td> 
            <td data-bind="text: uom"></td>            

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>   
 </div>     
</div>
```

This is the knockout code for adding user input to table:

```
// Make each item an observable object
var contractTableViewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]),
    contractReference: ko.observable(),
    farmReference: ko.observable(),
    productType: ko.observable(),
    productVariety: ko.observable(),
    grade: ko.observable(),
    season: ko.observable(),   
    dateCreated: ko.observable(),    
    dateAgreed: ko.observable(),   
    asGrown: ko.observable(),   
    committed: ko.observable(),     
    optional: ko.observable(),     
    moved: ko.observable(),     
    uom: ko.observable(),  


    // Add item to the array
    addItem: function () {
    this.items.push({
        contractReference: this.contractReference(),
        farmReference: this.farmReference(),
        productType: this.productType(),
        productVariety: this.productVariety(),
        grade: this.grade(),
        season: this.season(),
        dateCreated: this.dateCreated(),
        dateAgreed: this.dateAgreed(),
        asGrown: this.asGrown(),
        committed: this.committed(),
        optional: this.optional(),
        moved: this.moved(),
        uom: this.uom()
    });
   }
 }

// Initialised when page loads
ko.applyBindings(contractTableViewModel);
```

This is my form:

```
<div id="cForm">
<!-- Bind to observables from input boxes on form -->
 <form id="contract_form" action= "/api/contracts/" method="post">

     Contract Reference:

    <input type="text" id="cref" data-bind="value: contractReference">

    <br/><br/>Farm Reference:

    <input type="text" id="fref" data-bind="value: farmReference" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Product Type:

    <input type="text" id="ptype" data-bind="value: productType" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Product Variety:

    <input type="text" id="pvar" data-bind="value: productVariety" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Grade:

    <input type="text" name="grade" data-bind="value: grade" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Season:

    <input type="text" name="season" data-bind="value: season" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Date Created:

    <input type="text" name="dcreated" data-bind="value: dateCreated" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

    <br/><br/>Date Agreed:

    <input type="text" name="dagreed" data-bind="value: dateAgreed" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

     <br/><br/>Estimated As Grown Quantity:

    <input type="text" name="grown" data-bind="value: asGrown" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

     <br/><br/>Committed Quantity:

    <input type="text" name="comm" data-bind="value: committed" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

     <br/><br/>Optional Quantity:

    <input type="text" name="opt" data-bind="value: optional" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

     <br/><br/>Moved Quantity:

    <input type="text" name="moved" data-bind="value: moved" onclick="this.value=' ';" />

     <br/><br/>UOM:

    <input type="text" name="uom" data-bind="value: uom" onclick="this.value=' ';" />


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add new contract" data-bind="click: addItem" onclick="getValues();"/> <!-- Call addItem function -->

     <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
     <br/> <br/>

</form>
 </div>
```

So basically, if I put the form and the table on the same page then I can add data to the form and see it being updated in the table when I click the submit button, but what I am aiming for is for the user to input data on a separate page to then go back to the table page and see their input in the table.

Sidenote: I am also getting an error in the knockout code saying that ko isn't reference properly. I have included the script in the head of the page where the table is created, above the script for including the knockout file. I'm a bit confused as to why this is still happening?

(Hopefully this makes sense. If not please ask for clarification. Also please ask if you require to see any more of the code)

Comment: well without page reloading we have to pass data between two view models (your form and table are two partial views i guess) you should try like this http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/paxnd6uz/4/light/ . original documentation here http://www.wrapcode.com/knockoutjs/communication-between-multiple-view-models-in-knockoutjs-mvvm-the-right-approach/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should be trying to do something like this

Trick here is simple you just need to pass observableArray from viewModel1 to viewModel2 .

**View Model:**

```
var shouter = new ko.subscribable();
var viewModel1 = function(){
    this.array = ko.observableArray(); 
    this.add=function()
    {
      this.array.push({'message':'i am from vm1'});
    }.bind(this);

    this.array.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        shouter.notifySubscribers(newValue, "messageToPublish");
    });
};

var viewModel2 = function(vm1){
    this.message = ko.observable("");
    this.coolarray=ko.observableArray();
    shouter.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        this.coolarray(newValue);
    }, this, "messageToPublish");
};

var masterVM = (function(){
    this.viewModel1 =  new viewModel1(),
    this.viewModel2 = new viewModel2();
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM)
```

**View:**

```
<div data-bind="with:viewModel1">
  <button data-bind="click:add">ADD</button>
</div>

<div data-bind="with:viewModel2"> 
<div data-bind="foreach:coolarray">
    <p data-bind="text:message">
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/paxnd6uz/37/)**

Handy documentation on **[Pub-sub in Knockout, with Postbox](http://www.wrapcode.com/knockoutjs/communication-between-multiple-view-models-in-knockoutjs-mvvm-the-right-approach/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to submit a form from one page and populate its values on the second.

A quick and simple way of doing this is when you submit the form values from 'Page1' you get those values to the server(i.e. NodeJS/StandardJS) and then redirect it to 'Page2' where you populate the your viewModel.

To keep things simple and consistent you could use the same viewModel in both the pages.